# Tensor manipulation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am very new at manipulating tensors and I have the following equation:

$$A_{\mu \nu\tau} b^\mu c^\nu = g_{\tau \rho} d^\rho$$

where $\tau$ is the independent index and $g_{\tau \rho}$ the metric tensor is. Furthermore I've also used the Einstein convention.

I want to solve this equation for the contravariant vector $d$ but I'm not sure how I should get rid of the metric multiplying this vector. I thought of two possible solutions to get rid of the metric:

1) Divide by the metric (less likely to be correct)

2) Contract the whole equation with the metric with upper indices (very likely to be correct).

Which of the two options I presented above is the correct way to get rid of the metric?

Comment: 1) must be incorrect (that is not one term..... there's a summation). If you want a contravariant $d$, can you just do $d_\tau = g_{\tau \rho} d^\rho$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $g^{\sigma\tau}$ and use that
$$ g^{ab}g_{bc} = \delta^a_c, $$
so the right-hand side becomes $ d^{\sigma} $, which is what you want. I'll leave the left-hand side to you, since you don't say if you mind raising the index on $A_{\mu\nu\tau}$.

Comment: So the free index will be $\sigma$ after this operation?

Comment: Yes, it will be.